# Use existing pages instead of initialised controllers in PageViewController

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm using a PageViewController from [this](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit) tutorial

Since the pages are being added as controllers, here:

`controllers = parent.pages.map { UIHostingController(rootView: $0) }`

Whenever they're updated in my SwiftUI view, the user can't see any updates, since (i'm guessing) the `init` method doesn't refresh.

So how am I able to use the current `pages` instead of instantiating a `controllers` array?

Here is my code:

PageViewController.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct PageViewController<Page: View>: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var pages: [Page]
    var onLast: () -> AnyView
    @Binding var currentPage: Int

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIPageViewController {
        let pageViewController = UIPageViewController(
            transitionStyle: .scroll,
            navigationOrientation: .vertical)
        pageViewController.dataSource = context.coordinator
        pageViewController.delegate = context.coordinator

        return pageViewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, context: Context) {
        pageViewController.setViewControllers(
            [context.coordinator.controllers[currentPage]], direction: .forward, animated: true)
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {
        var parent: PageViewController
        var controllers = [UIViewController]()

        init(_ pageViewController: PageViewController) {
            parent = pageViewController
            controllers = parent.pages.map { UIHostingController(rootView: $0) }
        }

        func pageViewController(
            _ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
            viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
        {
            guard let index = controllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) else {
                return nil
            }
            if index == 0 {
                return controllers.last
            }
            return controllers[index - 1]
        }

        func pageViewController(
            _ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
            viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
        {
            guard let index = controllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) else {
                return nil
            }
            if index + 1 == controllers.count {
                return controllers.first
            }
            return controllers[index + 1]
        }

        func pageViewController(
            _ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
            didFinishAnimating finished: Bool,
            previousViewControllers: [UIViewController],
            transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
            if completed,
               let visibleViewController = pageViewController.viewControllers?.first,
               let index = controllers.firstIndex(of: visibleViewController) {
                if index + 1 == controllers.count {
                    print("index: \(index)")
                    print(controllers.count)
                    controllers.append(UIHostingController(rootView: parent.onLast()))
                }
                parent.currentPage = index
            }
        }
    }
}


struct PageView<Page: View>: View, Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: PageView<Page>, rhs: PageView<Page>) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    var pages: [Page]
    var onLast: () -> AnyView
    @Binding var currentPage: Int

    var body: some View {
        PageViewController(pages: pages, onLast: onLast, currentPage: $currentPage)
    }
}
```

SwiftUI View

```
import SwiftUI

struct Test: View {
    @State var color: Color = Color.blue
    
    var body: some View {
        PageView(
            pages: [
                AnyView(
                    color
                ),
                AnyView(
                    Color.purple
                ),
                AnyView(Color.green),
                AnyView(Color.orange),
            ],
             onLast: {
                    color = Color.red
                },
             currentPage: $currentPage
        )
        .equatable()
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I don't recall any problem with this `PageViewController`. What/how did you  try to update? Would you show demo?

Comment: @Asperi when I change `color` with `onLast` the first page, defined by `AnyView(color)` doesn't update, and `init` only runs once, so how is it supposed to update `controllers` with the new page data?

Answer (score 0):

Well, UIKit views should live in own world, SwiftUI views in own. Actually it is expected here that parent state will not update something deep inside bridged UIKit, even if it looks like it is in same stack, but actually it is just a function and it is called god-damn-known-when.

Anyway the approach is to solve it is simple - use SwiftUI tools to update SwiftUI views. Here it looks appropriate to use ObservableObject view model with explicit view observed it and work with that view model, because it is a reference-type.

Here is a sketch:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var color = Color.blue
}

struct Test: View {
    @StateObject var vm = ViewModel()   // << owner !!
    
    var body: some View {
        PageView(
            pages: [
                AnyView(
                    NativePath(vm: vm) // << inject
                ),
                AnyView(
                    Color.purple
                ),
                AnyView(Color.green),
                AnyView(Color.orange),
            ],
             onLast: {
                    vm.color = Color.red // << update by ref
                },
             currentPage: $currentPage
        )
        .equatable()
    }

    struct NativePath: View {
       @ObservedObject var vm: ViewModel  // << observe explicitly

       var body: some View {
         vm.color             // << updated
       }
    }
}
```